# Styling Divs with css

Tags: css, stylesheet

Whats the best way in order to style with css 3 div in this way:
Div 1 and 2 (same width) one up and one down on the left side and div 3 on the right side.
something like:

```
div1  { height: 200px; width:400px }
div2  { height: 600px; width:400px }
div3  { height: 800px; width:600px }
```

Comment: u can do something like `div1,div2 {width: 400px}` then declare each one separately according to the prop u want to assign to that div/class/id , also check this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp to have a better understand how to use css selectors.

Comment: Are you asking about a specific layout or are you just trying to DRY out your current code?

Comment: The layout i will use for my website is the one above, i am struggle to understand the best option in order to make the website responsive or "auto-collapse". But first I want to understand how to have 2 div up and down on the left side and one big div on the right side. Exemple site: www.followmytrip.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to first take two divs one should be to the left side and the other should be to the right side, the left one should have two more divs inside it. for example:

```css
/**** CSS FILE ****/
.left{
  float:left;
  }

.right{
  float:right;
  }

.div1{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  }

.div2{
  width:400px;
  height:600px;
  }

.div3{
  width:600px;
  height:800px;
  }
```

```html
<!-- HTML File -->

    <div class="left">
         <div class="div1"> <!-- My div1 --> div1 </div>
         <div class="div2"> <!-- My div2 --> div2 </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <div class="div3"> <!-- My div3 --> div3 </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I did so but the left side is not positioning well. I am doing it from scatch now.

Comment: fix it. i adopet this solution as more suitable for my needs. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You could use reusable `class`:

```
<div class="h200 w400">

</div>
<div class="h600 w400">

</div>
<div class="h800 w600">

</div>
```

and CSS

```
.h200{
  height:200px;
}
.h600 {
  height:600px
}
.h800 {
  height:800px;
}
.w400 {
  width:400px;
}
.w600 {
  width:600px
}
```

If you build your CSS with SASS (or similar) then this can be easily produced.

Comment: It looks a good idea. I did not know about it. I will give it a try.

Comment: @gigi you can use class to reuse same style , id for one peticular or reguar selector such as div or > or [class="myclass"], you have lots of option : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/ and you could basicly draw your basic layout like this : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbXGyY or with extra html http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNLPYv Enjoy the selector's power :)